# Aftershokz Headset Compatibility

Tags: bluetooth

We have a Cx with XP8, indicating they have issues using a certain brand of headset called 'aftershokz'.  This headset works on other android devices but not XP8.

Any idea what may be causing the problem?

Link to Aftershokz web page: https://aftershokz.com/us/products/openmove?gclid=Cj0KCQiA15yNBhDTARIsAGnwe0VtqFynZHJe9wjBrWO5kduguHBz9vcyXnYOIVC-_1cFf8ywucwDy14aArR9EALw_wcB

Comment: I have verified with another customer same issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be a focused programming problem as defined in the [help/on-topic]. Talk to Aftershokz. [We can't answer this kind of thing here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577).